# Recurring "expected" error in unity and can't find whats missing/wrong

Tags: c#, if-statement, compiler-errors, timer

I keep getting the error "Assets\scripts\PlayerMovement.cs(28,42): error CS1002: ; expected"
from unity console but, I can't find whats wrong in the area below.

```
    (Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"))
         {
             stopwatch.Start();
         }

                if ((stopwatch > 1) && (stopwatch < 2))
            {
                runSpeed = (runSpeed * 1.5);
            } 

                else if (stopwatch >= 2)
            {
                runSpeed = (runSpeed * 2);
            } 

        if (Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") = 0)
        {
             stopwatch.Stop();
        }
```

I tried removing the parenthesis and moving around the semicolons. I don't know what else I can do because I'm learning this stuff as a I go.

I'm trying to make it where the longer the player is moving left or right the faster they go in 3 different speeds. The default speed of 40, the second speed which is 60, and the third and final speed which is 80.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why did you put a single equal-sign in the last if-statement, you should try to put a second equal-sign in the last if-statement.

Because of that, it sets your method is set to zero in the if-statement but is not checked whether it is zero or not.
Just replace

```
if(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal")=0)
```

With

```
if(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal")==0)
```

Also in your very first line of code there is no if-statement, but the brackets exist, also in the very first line the condition is not check whether you are moving, so replace

```
(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"))
```

With

```
if(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal")!=0)
```

that might help

Comment: Also why are lines 6-14 in between those two major if-statements, can't you put those after the two Input-checks

Comment: Thank you this actually worked. After I fixed this though a few more errors appeared. It now states that my operators ">", "<", and ">=" cannot be applied to operands of type 'stopwatch' and 'int'. Any Suggestions?

Comment: Maybe this helps: if(stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds>1000&&stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds<2000) and else if(stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds>=2000) (beware that stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds uses int64 (Long Intergers))